# Ember-data - just a simple get request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to integrate ember-data with my RESTful API, but I am having trouble getting a `GET` request to work.

Searching for help was unhelpful because the results were outdated.

Can someone help me get a grasp on what the issues are with my setup? If I could get a `GET` request to work, that would be a big step to getting this working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include code of what you've tried and what has/hasn't worked next time.

Here's a simple example, if you remove the mockjax it will make a call to the server at `/colors`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/73/edit

Comment: Thanks man, I really haven't any Idea so it was hard to include code because i've tried it many times with many different code snippets. But your example helped me a lot thanks :)